# How Internally BTree and Bitmap Index stored in oracle?

Tags: oracle10g

I want to know what value is stored against BTree Index and Bitmap Index in oracle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search the [documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#sthref966) for "internal structure of indexes".